Scary movie about a family
I watched this movie when I was very young and it absolutely scared me but I can't for the life of my remember what it was. 
I don't remember much but what I do remember is a family moves into a new house and there is this wreath in it and the family is being attacked by people (sorry I know this isn't specific at all). So this girl, I believe, who was pretending to be friends with the family's daughter, convinces them to burn the wreath saying that it was causing them harm. Then, once they do it, she reveals that it was in fact the only thing keeping them safe. 
Sorry that that's all I remember but I think my brain blocked out most of it. 

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

The movie is part of the Goosebumps TV series Welcome to Dead House: Part one from 1997 (season 2 episode 20).
The Goosebumps series are based upon books by Author R.L. Stine.
From IMDb:http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1097930/

Thirteen-year-old Amanda has to leave her friends and home behind to
  live in a gloomy industrial town. Unknown to her a sinister accident
  years ago at the Dark Falls chemical factory poisoned all the workers
  and turned them into mutated entities, and she has to prove to her
  family that something is going on before it's too late. 

The family displays a family heirloom (which is a wreath) in the home to ward off evil spirits.
One of the "mutated entities" (who is a girl) persuades 13 year old Amanda to burn it.
